# ¿Cómo validar un sql_query antes de realizar la consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Asumimos que tengo una consulta *MySQL* en *PHP*:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
```

Quisiera validar su formato antes de hacer una apertura al servidor, es decir:

```
validar($sql)
```

Lo que debería devolver `true` porque está correcto.

Pero si la consulta ahora es...

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM tabla";
```

... debería devolver `false`.

Esto es una explicación sencilla, estuve revisando varios foros y se consiguen validaciones de sintaxis en *Python*, *NPM* y hasta en *JavaScript*, pero no logro conseguirlo con ***PHP***.

Comment: Espero no equivocarme esta vez, pero creo que te refieres a [QUERY BY SQL](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv16/4D/16.4/QUERY-BY-SQL.301-3978285.es.html)

Comment: Me temo que vas a tener que picartelo directamente.

Comment: @Daap me temo que no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: No, no es **QUERY BY SQL** pero un amigo me está ayudando a construir la función de manera general para asi utilizarla, el motivo es porque hay ocasiones que hacemos un select o insert y se nos olvida la sintaxis correcta hacemos la consulta al servidor y PUM! Error, perdemos ese tiempo y utilizamos MySQL en vano, así que vamos a validar la sintaxis antes de realizar la consulta y ya luego pues MySQL que se encargue.

Comment: Puede que [esto](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-sql-parser/) te interese, o [esta extensión de pear](http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser), o [este proyecto de Github](https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser), o bien [esto](https://packagist.org/packages/phpmyadmin/sql-parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible alternativa sería usar una capa de abstracción de base de datos, pero mejor algo ya existente, hacerlo a mano es un proyecto en sí mismo.

Al principio probablemente te cueste comenzar, pero al final hará tu programación más ágil y podrás olvidarte de las consultas hechas *ad hoc* para las tareas comunes, a la vez que tendrás un montón de herramientas adicionales.

> **ORM**
>
> Object-Relational mapping, o lo que es lo mismo, mapeo de
>   objeto-relacional, es un modelo de programación que consiste en la
>   transformación de las tablas de una base de datos, en una serie de
>   entidades que simplifiquen las tareas básicas de acceso a los datos
>   para el programador.
>
> Para acceder de forma efectiva a la base de datos desde un contexto
>   orientado a objetos, es necesaria una interfaz que traduzca la lógica
>   de los objetos a la lógica relacional, esta interfaz se llama ORM
>   (object-relational mapping) o “mapeo de objetos a bases de datos”, y
>   está formada por objetos que permiten acceder a los datos y que
>   contienen en sí mismos el código necesario para hacerlo.
>
> La principal ventaja de la capa de abstracción es la portabilidad,
>   porque hace posible el cambiar la aplicación a otra base de datos,
>   incluso en mitad del desarrollo de un proyecto. Si se debe desarrollar
>   rápidamente un prototipo de una aplicación y el cliente no ha decidido
>   todavía la base de datos que mejor se ajusta a sus necesidades, se
>   puede construir la aplicación utilizando SQLite y cuando el cliente
>   haya tomado la decisión, cambiar fácilmente a MySQL, PostgreSQL u
>   Oracle. Solamente es necesario cambiar una línea en un archivo de
>   configuración y todo funciona correctamente.
>
> Fuente: [Tácito y explícito: Abstracción de bases de datos para PHP](https://tacitoyexplicito.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/abstraccion-de-bases-de-datos-para-php/)

Puedes buscar algo de información sobre los más conocidos, por ejemplo:

[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) y [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/) ([Manel Pérez: ¿Qué es Doctrine ORM?](https://manelperez.com/programacion/que-es-doctrine-orm/))

Aquí tratan el tema: [Mejor PHP DAL (capa de abstracción de datos) hasta el momento](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/2004232)